# how to resolve activeMQ msyql cluster get Attempting to acquire the exclusive lock error?

Tags: mysql, activemq-classic

I want to config activeMQ master/slave cluster by msyql.  What I do :
First to create two instances configs.

```
activemq create instanceA
activemq create instanceC
```

Then modify the port and mysql adapter, instanceA has:

```
 //conf  
 <persistenceAdapter >
        <!-- <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/> -->
         <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"  dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

 <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

 <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
       ---
    </bean>
```

instanceC has :

```
  --conf
 <persistenceAdapter >
            <!-- <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/> -->
             <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"  dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
 <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61619?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5673?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61615?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1884?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61600?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

<bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
       ---
    </bean>
```

Finally, I start instanceC `./instanceC start`, work fine. And I start instanceA `./instanceA start`, get error:

```
2016-09-30 18:11:42,612 | INFO  | Attempting to acquire the exclusive lock to become the Master broker | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
2016-09-30 18:12:33,760 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are done =)  That message means the instanceA is correctly polling for the exclusive lock on the data store. If you shutdown instanceC, you will see instanceA take over as primary.